# Is there a way to reassign a grid layout to a label?

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I have created a GUI with the aid of `Tkinter` that has created a 3 [C]olomn by 8 [R]ow, *(I have placed the borders of the 'cells' in red)* and output is like so:

[image]

Just to calrify:

Where the "logo [E]" is (C1,R1) & (C1,R2) are `rowspan`ned and where the "main window" is from (C2,R3) to (C3,R8) are `colomnspan`ned and `rowspan`ned.

All are Label widget except for (C1,R3 to C1,R8), which are button widgets with a `command` to display a string in "Main Window" (gray area).

My aim is to make the "Main Window"(gray area) display only in different grid layouts based on the selected button on the left. So for example I would like to make the grey have a grid layout of 2col by 4 row when C1,R6 is pressed, or when  C1,R3 is pressed the grid layout to be 2Cx6R all in the gray area.

**Q:** Is there a way of re-gridding a label? If so how? Or an alternative approach?

**ADDENDUM:**
Ideally I would like to update the GREEN area with different number of row and column configurations. *For example: When* Micro Audit *is touched, the Green area will configure itself to have 4 rows by 2 columns, and when Find Item is selected, it will only 3 rows with 1 column, etc. :*

[image]

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ Why did you delete it though? There was only a little mistake in there which actually can be fixed without much effort. Also, sorry if I sounded rude in that comment.

Comment: @Lafexlos No, no, you were not rude at all :)  There are members who downvote correct and tested answers without mentioning the reason, so .... Just answer to this yourself and you will get +1 from me for your positive attitude and good answers you are used to provide here